# Reducer does not render Component even though reducer returns new object

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux

I'm still kinda new in using Redux inside React Native components. I'm facing a problem which I cannot solve for days now. Namely, I'm trying to get my navigation data, ie. latitude. What I want to do is to attach it to the redux state and get its value every 2 seconds. So inside of my component I'm using setInterval which runs my redux flow every 2 sec. On the way back to react component I would expect to have this state rerendered every time, but this is not what's happening. I'm getting it only once. I fallowed the similar issues here and in all the problem was not returning new object from a reducer. But I guess this is not my case.
THANK YOU IN ADVANCE!
Here's my code:

MY COMPONENT GEOBATTERY:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { ScrollView, View, Text } from 'react-native';
import { Button } from './Button';
import {  
    appStoped, 
    setCoordinates, 
    updateGeolocationArray, 
     } from '../actions';

class GeoBattery extends Component {
    handleStart() {        
        const geolocationArray = [];
        let geolocationCounter = 0;

        this.geoLocationInterval = setInterval(() => {
            navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
                (position) => {
                    const latitude = position.coords.latitude;
                    const longitude = position.coords.longitude;
                    console.log(latitude);
                    this.props.setCoordinates(latitude, longitude);
                }, 
              );
              geolocationArray.push({ id: geolocationCounter++, latitude: this.props.latitude, longitude: this.props.longitude });
              this.props.updateGeolocationArray(geolocationArray);
        }, 1000);
    }

    handleStop() {
        clearInterval(this.geoLocationInterval);
    }

    handleNewLatitudeItems() {
        return this.props.geolocationArrayToMap.map(item => {
            return <Text key={item.id}> {item.latitude} </Text>;
        });
    }

    render() {
        console.log(this.props.latitude); // here it does not rerender
    const { buttonStyle, resultsStyle, resultContainer } = styles;
            return (
            <ScrollView style={buttonStyle}>
                <Button onPress={() => this.handleStart()}>START</Button>
                <Button onPress={() => this.handleStop()}>STOP</Button>
                <View style={resultContainer}>
                    <View style={{ flex: 4 }}>
                        <Text style={resultsStyle}> Lat: </Text>
                        <Text style={{ fontSize: 12 }}> { this.handleNewLatitudeItems() } </Text>
                    </View>
                </View>
            </ScrollView>
        );
    }
}

const styles = {
    buttonStyle: {
        marginTop: 20,
        marginBottom: 20,
    },
    resultContainer: {
        display: 'flex',
        flexDirection: 'row',
    },
    resultsStyle: {
        flex: 3,
        fontSize: 15,
        marginTop: 10,
        textAlign: 'center'
    }
  };

  const mapStateToProps = state => {
      console.log(state.update.geolocationArrayToMap); //here it return what I need to map and dynamically create new list items of latitude
    return {
        latitude: state.coords.latitude,
        geolocationArrayToMap: state.update.geolocationArrayToMap,
    };
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps, { appStoped, setCoordinates, updateGeolocationArray })(GeoBattery);
```

MY ACTIONS:

```
import { 
    CLEAR_DATA, 
    SET_COORDS, 
    UPDATE_GEOLOCATION_ARRAY, 
     } from './types';

export const appStoped = () => {
    return {
        type: CLEAR_DATA
    };
};

 export const setCoordinates = (latitude, longitude) => {
     return {
         type: SET_COORDS,
         payload1: latitude,
         payload2: longitude
     };
 };

 export const updateGeolocationArray = (geolocationArray) => {
     return {
         type: UPDATE_GEOLOCATION_ARRAY,
         payload: geolocationArray
     };
 };
```

TYPES:

```
export const CLEAR_DATA = 'clear_data';
export const SET_COORDS = 'set_coords';
export const UPDATE_GEOLOCATION_ARRAY = 'update_geolocation_array';
```

MY INDEX REDUCER:

```
import { combineReducers } from 'redux';
import CoordsReducer from './CoordsReducer';
import UpdateReducer from './UpdateReducer';


export default combineReducers({
    coords: CoordsReducer,
    update: UpdateReducer,    
});
```

MY COORDSREDUCER:

```
import { SET_COORDS, CLEAR_DATA } from '../actions/types';

const INITIAL_STATE = {
    latitude: '',
};

export default (state = INITIAL_STATE, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case SET_COORDS:
            return { ...state, latitude: action.payload1 };
        case CLEAR_DATA:
            return { ...state, ...INITIAL_STATE };
        default:
            return state;
    }
};
```

MY UPDATEREDUCER:

```
import { UPDATE_GEOLOCATION_ARRAY, CLEAR_DATA } from '../actions/types';

const INITIAL_STATE = {
    geolocationArrayToMap: [],
};

export default (state = INITIAL_STATE, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case UPDATE_GEOLOCATION_ARRAY:
            return { ...state, geolocationArrayToMap: action.payload };
        case CLEAR_DATA:
            return { ...state, ...INITIAL_STATE };
        default:
            return state;
    }
};
```

MYSTORE:

```
import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from 'redux';
import ReduxThunk from 'redux-thunk';
import reducers from './reducers';


const store = createStore(reducers, {}, applyMiddleware(ReduxThunk));

export default store;
```

Comment: How long does it take to for the callback in `navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition` to get fired? In other words, does it take less than 1 second each time to get your current position?

Comment: Well, I guess it takes almost nothing beacuse I'm using simulator with a simulated values so it does not need to connect outside. Even if I change setInterval to 10 seconds it causes the same problem: I'm getting a value only once, not as many times as setInterval fires.

Comment: Is your coords reducer stupposed to have the "1":  `action.payload1`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your are mutating the array you send to your action :

```
geolocationArray.push({ id: geolocationCounter++, latitude: this.props.latitude, longitude: this.props.longitude });
this.props.updateGeolocationArray(geolocationArray);
```

Try using an immutable way to do it :

```
this.props.updateGeolocationArray([...geolocationArray, { id: geolocationCounter++, latitude: this.props.latitude, longitude: this.props.longitude }]);
```

Comment: Bravo! You are right! Thank you for that. I thought that what I'm sending can be mutated and only reducers cannot. Could you explain why this happens?